# Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: support, faq, stack-exchange, technology

What tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?

See also: [Which tools and technologies are used to build Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/what-technologies-are-used-to-build-data-explorer/52063#52063)

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931/)

Comment: See also [Does StackExchange 2.0 Share the Same CodeBase with SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/does-stackexchange-2-0-share-the-same-codebase-with-so)

Comment: See also: [What technologies were used to build the chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/what-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-chat) (though this currently has no real answers.)

Comment: See also [Stack Exchange’s Architecture in Bullet Points](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/) on the blog.

Comment: See also [Stack Exchange: Planning for failure](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2012/02/15/planning-for-failure/) and other posts on Nick's blog.

Comment: This is an implementation detail, you should only care about what's documented :P

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Technologies_used

Answer (score 686):

## Core

Stack Overflow uses a [**WISC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177901/what-does-wisc-stack-mean) stack <strike>via [BizSpark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/15/stack-overflow-and-bizspark/)</strike> (we graduated!):

- **Operating System** [Microsoft Windows Server 2019 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/)
- **Web Server** [IIS 10](https://www.iis.net/)
- **Database** [SQL Server 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019) running [Microsoft Windows Server 2016 x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/34846/in-place-upgrade-from-windows-server-standard-to-enterprise-or-datacenter)
- **Language** [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))

### Software Development Tools

- **IDE** Visual Studio 2019
- **Framework** [Microsoft .NET 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET)
- **Web Framework** [ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) with [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/)
- **View Engine** [Razor](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)
- **Browser Framework** [jQuery 1.12.4](https://jquery.com/)
- **Data Access Layer** [Entity Framework Core 2.2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) and [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)
- **Cache / Additional Data** redis 4.0.7 via [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis), with serialization via [protobuf-net](https://nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net)
- **Source Control** [Git](https://git-scm.com/) using a [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home) instance hosted by GitHub (previously self-hosted GitHub, [Mercurial](https://mercurial.selenic.com/) from 2010–2014, [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) from 2008–2010)
- **Compare Tool** [Beyond Compare 4](https://www.scootersoftware.com/)

### External Bits

Code used in Stack Overflow that is not included as part of the development tools:

- [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)
- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)
- [WMD](https://code.google.com/p/wmd/) - Now developed as open source in the project *[PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)*
- [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) (was Prettify)
- [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)
- [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/)
- [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186406/152859))
- [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org)
- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co//) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange))

### Miscellaneous

- [WordPress on Linux](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/blog-outage-backup-policies/) (Site Blogs) [Jekyll (on linux?)](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/) (for [blog.stackexchange.com](https://stackoverflow.blog/))
- [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/) (for [real time updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox); [custom C# implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168148/152859))
- [Bandwidth used by Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172340/152859)
- [jQuery Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin (for the [grid-style site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid))  <sup><sub>([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124086/))</sub></sup>

### Content

- **License** [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC); [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for content contributed between 2011-04-08 and 2018-05-01 (UTC); [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) for content contributed before 2011-04-08 (UTC) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates))
- **Standards** [OpenSearch](https://www.opensearch.org/), [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29)
- **Host** two datacenters:

  - New York: [QTS](https://www.qtsdatacenters.com/) (technically in Jersey City, NJ now). Formerly hosted at [Internap](https://www.internap.com/) and [PEER 1](https://www.peer1.com/).
  - Denver: [FORTRUST](https://www.fortrustdatacenter.com/)

### Hardware

- 11 Dell R640 IIS web servers (9 shared for all production like SO, two for Meta and development):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Processor Gold 6226 @ 2.7 GHz 12 Core with 24 threads
  - 96 GB RAM
  - Windows Server 2019
  - Two drives

    - 2 Toshiba 480GB SAS SSD (RAID 1)
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s [NIC teaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)

- Three Dell R720xd database servers (two in New York City, one in Denver, using SQL AlwaysOn Clustering) (Global "Sites" DB & Stack Overflow dedicated):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Processor E5-2680 @ 2.7 GHz
  - 384 GB RAM
  - 21 drives

    - Mirrored Pair for OS
    - 2 Intel P3700 2TB PCIe NVMe RAID1 for databases
    - 24 Intel 710 200GB SSD RAID10 for databases
  - SQL Server 2014 SP1
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming

- Three Dell R730 database servers (two in New York City, one in Denver, using SQL AlwaysOn Clustering) (All other sites, Careers, Area 51, etc.):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Processor X5680 @ 3.33 GHz
  - 768 GB RAM
  - 28 drives

    - Mirrored Pair for OS
    - 2 Intel P3700 2TB PCIe NVMe RAID0 for databases
    - 24 1.2TB 10K RAID10 for large databases
  - SQL Server 2014 SP1
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming

- Two Dell R640 HAProxy servers (direct):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Gold 5218 @ 2.3 GHz
  - 96 GB RAM
  - CentOS 7
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming (internal)
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming (external)

- Two Dell R640 HAProxy servers (CloudFlare):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Gold 5218 @ 2.3 GHz
  - 96 GB RAM
  - CentOS 7
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming (internal)
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming (external)

- 2 Dell R640 Redis servers:

  - 2x Intel Xeon Gold 6244 @ 3.6 GHz
  - 384 GB RAM
  - CentOS 7
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming

- Three Dell R640 Service servers for tag engine/search:

  - 2x Intel Xeon Gold 6244 @ 3.6 GHz
  - 96 GB RAM

- One Dell R620 Backup server running NetBackup (most backups):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Processor E52620 @ 2.0 GHz
  - 16 GB RAM
  - 14 drives

    - Mirrored Pair for OS
    - 12 4TB 10K RPM RAID10 for backups (DAS)
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming

- One Dell R730xd SMB3 Backup server (SQL backups):

  - 2x Intel Xeon Processor E5-2623v3 @ 3.0 GHz
  - 16 GB RAM
  - 30 drives

    - Mirrored Pair for OS
    - 16 6TB 7.2K RPM RAID10 for backups (Internal)
    - 12 4TB 10K RPM RAID10 for backups (DAS)
  - 2x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming

- Six Dell R640 VMWare ESX servers:

  - 2x Intel Xeon Gold 6240 @ 2.60 GHz
  - 1.5 TB RAM
  - 16x 10 Gbit/s NIC teaming (8x 10 Gbit/s per FX2s)

- 2 Cisco ASR1001-X routers
- 2 ASR1001 Routers
- 2 Fortinet 1100E Firewalls
- 2 Cisco Nexus 5596 Cores in an active/active redundant configuration

Sources:

1. [Stack Overflow's New York Data Center (Server Fault Blog)](https://blog.serverfault.com/2010/10/29/1432571770/)
2. [Designing for Scalability of Management and Fault Tolerance (Server Fault Blog)](https://blog.serverfault.com/2010/09/10/1097492931/)
3. [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/21/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)
4. [Stack Overflow Server Glamour Shots](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/14/stack-overflow-rack-glamour-shots/)
5. [Technology and SEO profile for stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/28/our-dedicated-server/)
6. [Stack Overflow and DVCS](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/23/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/)
7. [Stack Overflow Network Configuration](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/14/stack-overflow-network-configuration/)
8. https://stackexchange.com/performance

Comment: Hmmm, the list seems incomplete. I don't see [Unicornify](http://unicornify.appspot.com/) in there...

Comment: I love how people are so into bc3 that they it is listed as part of the stack

Comment: Can I ask how on earth the SO team managed to update the site to user Razor so quickly? Did they actually port older aspx views into razor or are legacy pages running with razor side-by-side?

Comment: What is the platform/code that the [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) is run on?  I've posted a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93957/what-software-is-used-for-blog-stackexchange-com) on this already.

Comment: How StackOverflow Earns Revenue?

Comment: Probably should include this one as well http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216324/what-does-stack-overflow-use-for-its-community-wiki-edits-comparison-feature/216326#216326

Comment: I see VMWare in there somewhere, but could you please elaborate which systems are Bare Metal and which are running under virtualization, perhaps Hyper-V?

Comment: What IoC Container is used by StackOverflow?

Comment: I have to say I was surprised to see this level of technical detail made public. I'm not sure how common this is, but my gut tells me that security pedants wouldn't be overjoyed by it. That is, purely theoretically, a malicious party might be able to narrow the space of attack options based on the level of details here. Just my two cents.

Comment: What about the ads management system ?

Comment: Is api.stackexchange.com included here?

Comment: "Microsoft Windows Server **2017** x64" - What? Did MS release a special version of Windows Server between 2016 and 2019 exclusively for Stack's use?

Comment: The drive total for the "Dell R720xd database servers" doesn't add up.  Top level item says 21 drives, but has 28 itemized underneath.

Comment: This answer needs two updates: 1. [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/289905), but they still use MarkdownSharp and PageDown to some extent for special features; don’t know how much into detail this post should go. 2. [An Update On Creative Commons Licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344491/289905); they don’t use CC BY-SA 4.0 for _all_ the content. They use 2.5, 3.0, and 4.0.

Comment: @user289905: Sounds like it's worth bountying the question? :) I've updated the licensing info (well, I suggested an edit), but I don't know how/where best to work in the CommonMark info.

Comment: The answer is quite old it seems. Has it been updated?

Comment: What is used on the front-end? Only jQuery? Also, why such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @sammy34 probably you should stop storing your credit card info in your stackexchange profile, then.

Comment: Does stackoverflow have any plans to move to a distributed SQL database like cockroachdb, or has SQL AlwaysOn Clustering been good enough (i.e. with read-only nodes, iirc) to service people in different parts of the world?

Comment: @Josh is the move completed? Think I saw a report yesterday with Fastly error.

Comment: @JohnnyFun you won't get a reply here, better start a new question for that.