# DB Architecture of stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, architecture, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the architecture details of Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow)

I admire the instant responses of SO. I wonder how the database was built?

What's the architecture? You don't need to disclose the exact thing but an idea to everyone will help.

Answer (score 4):

[What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

[What are the architecture details of Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow)

[Stack Overflow Architecture](http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture)