# What is the architecture of SO?

Tags: discussion, open-source, architecture

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are the architecture details of Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow)
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Does anyone know the architecture of Stack Overflow?
I did a quick Google search but did not find any open source clones.

Comment: There's a google tech talk about SO giving somedetails .. maybe there's more, but this is a Q for meta

Comment: How many times has this been asked?  At least five, maybe more.  For instance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

First link when I googled "stackoverflow architecture."

http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/8/5/stack-overflow-architecture.html

Answer (score 1):

[SO Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ), also when it's up the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) talks about the architecture and even hardware a fair bit.