# Is there somehow a way to find the questions which are the most referred to when closing duplicates?

Tags: discussion, moderation, duplicate-questions

Duplicated questions are a thing we want to avoid on these sites. However, it will happen anyway, this is why we get the "exact duplicate" close reason.

There are some questions which are coming back frequently, and they are closed as duplicate of an initial one, usually. For questions which are coming back the most, it could be good to take over the original question to improve it (because often it was badly asked, compared to a duplicate, which is finally a bit silly, but it has the most answers). Eventually, it could be nice to even make some CW, so that they become references.

Besides the fact of "Is it a good idea to take over a question someone else asked, *for the greater good*?", there is the question of "how to find these?". I know that so far, the link to duplicate is only included in the question, which is potentially editable, so it's not a solid reference.

Besides this constraint, **is there a way to find which are the questions which are the most referred to in a duplicate context?**

I know it is not possible with the current search tools, but maybe it could be with a data dump? As a further idea, would this have an interest in being formalized (like for example including the main duplicate link to the close description), and eventually have a "top duplicates" accessible in moderation tools?

Comment: I for one would like this, to improve the quality of the most referred to question and close all related ones on sight

Comment: This should definitely be available in the moderation/10k tools.

Comment: I'd like to see more data in the data dump in order to produce queries like this. Please vote for this related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The improved close-as-dupe page shows the similar posts and count of posts linked to as the duplicate to the similar post.

[image: new-improved!]

Answer (score 8):

These only count those dupes where the "possible duplicate" link(s) where inserted automatically; this feature hasn't always been in the site. I just used a very simple matching algorithm, too, so take the numbers with a pinch of salt. Only shows the top twenty (for Server Fault only those with more than one dupe). Based on the February data dump.

**Meta:**

- 19 dupes: [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369)
- 11 dupes: [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88)
- 11 dupes: [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)
- 10 dupes: [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093)
- 8 dupes: [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331)
- 8 dupes: [Trilogy Portal: Community Colloboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033)
- 7 dupes: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431)
- 7 dupes: [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988)
- 7 dupes: [What are "Community Wiki" posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740)
- 6 dupes: [How does "Reputation" work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237)
- 6 dupes: [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865)
- 6 dupes: [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227)
- 6 dupes: [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353)
- 6 dupes: [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615)
- 6 dupes: [Has Stack Overflow been haiku-hacked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509)
- 5 dupes: [Is there a page that displays questions with zero answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675)
- 4 dupes: [Stack Overflow Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267)
- 4 dupes: [What are the architecture details of Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498)
- 4 dupes: [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459)
- 4 dupes: [Isn't the "vote too old to be changed" a little too eager?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25202)

**Stack Overflow:**

- 8 dupes: [What's your take on the programming language Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712172)
- 7 dupes: [How do the equality (==) and identity (===) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646)
- 7 dupes: [What IDE to use for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584)
- 6 dupes: [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711)
- 6 dupes: [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which "equal" operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494)
- 5 dupes: [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394)
- 5 dupes: [Best Java book you have read so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102)
- 5 dupes: [What PHP framework would you choose for a new application and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648)
- 5 dupes: [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174)
- 5 dupes: [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323)
- 5 dupes: [What is the easiest language to start with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769)
- 5 dupes: [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037)
- 5 dupes: [Which is faster/best? SELECT *  or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512)
- 4 dupes: [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901)
- 4 dupes: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073)
- 4 dupes: [Why does one often see "null != variable" instead of "variable != null" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561)
- 4 dupes: [What does the @ symbol before a variable name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529)
- 4 dupes: [Properties vs Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601621)
- 4 dupes: [What bug tracking software do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328)
- 4 dupes: [Can Go compiler be installed on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717652)

**Super User:**

- 11 dupes: [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493)
- 8 dupes: [Installing Mac OS X on Non Apple Hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/47337)
- 7 dupes: [Free antivirus solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2)
- 5 dupes: [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248)
- 5 dupes: [How to install Ubuntu, Windows XP and Windows 7 from scratch as triple-boot system](https://superuser.com/questions/41595)
- 4 dupes: [Replacement for Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/90)
- 4 dupes: [What is your favourite service for bloggers?](https://superuser.com/questions/8702)
- 4 dupes: [Best opensource FTP software?](https://superuser.com/questions/12869)
- 4 dupes: [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801)
- 4 dupes: [Windows XP and RAM 3.5GB+](https://superuser.com/questions/27086)
- 4 dupes: [What are some "must have" Windows programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1241)
- 4 dupes: [Where to purchase computer parts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1477)
- 4 dupes: [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/5631)
- 4 dupes: [Windows backup by Imaging](https://superuser.com/questions/7739)
- 4 dupes: [Daily-Reading for General Geekiness.](https://superuser.com/questions/1611)
- 4 dupes: [Compaq Presario 6608Au Blue Screen problem](https://superuser.com/questions/87629)
- 4 dupes: [Free Windows ISO Mounting Software](https://superuser.com/questions/3804)
- 4 dupes: [Which Windows tweaks do you use and they actually work?](https://superuser.com/questions/3864)
- 3 dupes: [Free DVD recorder](https://superuser.com/questions/36)
- 3 dupes: ["Must Have" Windows Mobile Software](https://superuser.com/questions/2141)

**Server Fault:**

- 3 dupes: ["Extra Printers" in XP under Fusion 2.05](https://serverfault.com/questions/99264)
- 2 dupes: [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766)
- 2 dupes: [SQL Compliance Manager](https://serverfault.com/questions/67722)
- 2 dupes: [Best Windows remote support / screen sharing tools?](https://serverfault.com/questions/155)
- 2 dupes: [Who is a good registrar these days?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31392)
- 2 dupes: [hosting your own DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744)
- 2 dupes: [what's the syntax for Accessing smb/windows shares via alternative ports?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39180)
- 2 dupes: [Sharing Domain name between domain controller and webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/38208)

Comment: Awesome, it's funny to see what questions are apperently asked over and over again

Comment: Time to create a new list of "fave" questions on SU.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's great!

Comment: Another super-common dupe that I swear I see every day: "what's the hardest code you've ever written?"

Comment: 2 and a half years on, and I would love to see the top dupes for SO... Is there a data explorer query for this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good idea!

I can see a big potential for this. For instance on Super User, there are like a gazillion questions about "[syncing 2 folders](https://superuser.com/search?q=sync+folders)" and dupes come in almost every day. I still need to look for the original though. So having a list of all these kind op "mother-dupes" would be awesome.