# How can I find all questions marked as Duplicate of a particular question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there somehow a way to find the questions which are the most referred to when closing duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38793/is-there-somehow-a-way-to-find-the-questions-which-are-the-most-referred-to-when)

Just came across a case where, in hindsight I considered a question to be overly broad. ie., I'd prefer to argue that it should be closed as too broad instead of closing a lot of specific questions as dups.

How do I find out which questions have been asked so far that were closed as duplicates of this particular post? Bonus points if it also detects dups-of-dups as well (ie. C is closed as duplicate of B which is closed as dup of A)

Comment: This is so meta.

Comment: @random: could you kindly point out the answer to this question among answers to the question that you've marked as "possible duplicate"? I see none.