# How do I find questions that are marked as duplicates of a given one?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

It is easy to go from a duplicate question to its original: there is a link in the body of the question. But how do I go in the reverse direction (from a single original question to a list of duplicates)?

I don't see anything in [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

I saw [How can I find all questions marked as Duplicate of a particular question? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142900/how-can-i-find-all-questions-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-particular-question) question that is marked (incorrectly) as a duplicate of [Is there somehow a way to find the questions which are the most referred to when closing duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38793/137096) question that has no answer to this particular question.

For example, how do I find all duplicate questions where [Weighted random sample in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13047806/4279) is marked as the original?

Comment: Although not a complete answer (hence the comment): if a question has been marked as a dupe, then both the dupe and the original will have a link to the other in the 'Linked' sidebar - you could click each one to find the one you want...