# Is it possible to limit the linked questions list using additional search criteria?

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions

For example, [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13047806?q=duplicate%3Ayes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13047806?q=duplicate%3Ayes)  shows the questions linked to/from question with `13047806` id. Note: the query `duplicate:yes` in the link is ignored: the search box shows 'duplicate:yes' but the result list has questions that are not duplicates. Is there a way to enable `duplicate:yes` here?

Related: [How do I find questions that are marked as duplicates of a given one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252797/137096)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with the search engine on the site but you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if you're OK if the data can be up to an week old.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/296560) shows the post that is linked with posts that are duplicate:

```sql
select distinct 
       pl.relatedpostid as [Post Link]
     , pl.postid as [Post Link]
from postLinks pl
inner join postlinks dl on dl.postid = pl.postid 
                       and dl.linktypeid =3 -- duplicate
where 1=1
  and pl.relatedpostid = 13047806
```

The [PostLinks table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) holds rows for LinkTypes 1 (linked) and  3 (duplicate).
The column `relatedpostid` holds the target, while the column `postid` holds the source. By joining the postlinks table again on postid where linktype=3 you get your desired result.

Comment: I don't want posts *with* duplicate links. I want to find posts that *are* duplicates of a given post. See [linked posts with `[duplicate]` in the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13047806?q=duplicate%3Ayes)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think I fixed it, it now reports at least two of the three duplicates. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426266/python-random-sample-with-probabilities) isn't in the result but I think that is due to the fact that SEDE is not yet updated.

Comment: It works. [I've simplified it slightly](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/296623/posts-duplicates) (I'm not sure I understand the schema)

Comment: On closer inspection, It does not return the duplicates of a given question.

Comment: If you are expecting 13047806 to be a duplicate target then my first query was correct because there are no questions that have 13047806 as duplicate...

Comment: yes. It appears [@Shog9's query should be used to get the duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217421/137096).