# Information (not from SO blogs) about the MVC Architecture of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, design, architecture, research

I found this link with a similar question but it did not contain the *exact* awnser I was looking to get:

[What are the architecture details of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stackoverflow)

I came across some lengthy articles on the Architecture of SO that were written independently of the SO creators, and also provided opinions on the design and its usage which I found quite interesting. I swore I saved off the links but I can't find them for anything. I think there was even a Microsoft MSDN article or Blog post about this topic, which I would like to see again.

I searched the net and did not find what I was looking for. Does anyone have the information about this sites Arcitecture written from an outside (non SO) perspective?

Comment: What do you mean by "non SO perspective"? Can it be posted here on MSO as long as it wasn't written by an SE team member?

Comment: Ah, like I mentioned from a MSFT blogger, dev blogger, etc. Not an article that originated from Jon or SO. Nothing against that documentation; its direct from the source, but there were some outside opinions and discussions I was looking for. Hopefully my explination is clear, I apologize if it is vague.

Comment: Your best source of information is going to be from insiders.  Why would you solicit opinions from people who have never been exposed to the technology?

Comment: Yikes! How do I offend with asking a question? How is it so confusing. As simple as I can ask it: Please provide links about the MVC Architecture of StackOverflow that *do not* originate from a SO site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam Saffron blogged about his experiences optimizing Linq to SQL to improve Stack Overflow's performance here: [How I learned to stop worrying and write my own ORM](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM)